"lebt seit X jahren in Y", why is this in present form, but the meaning is in the past perfect?

lebt seit X jahren in Y

Why is this in the present form, but the meaning is in the past perfect?
Why is it not:

hat gelebt seit X jahren in Y

?

Present tense: He is still living. Past tense: He does not live there anymore. Maybe he moved away, or died.

I am bemused that you think "the meaning" is how it is done in English. Most languages with which I am familiar use the present tense in this sort of statement, for example French.

This is because German tenses function differently from English tenses. In English, the adverbial for X years triggers perfect aspect. And if you want to say that some action is ongoing you add progressive aspect on top. E.g.

Martin has been living in England for ten years.

He is still living there. Compare English present perfect:

Martin has lived in England for ten years.

It's completed, he does not live there any more.

We don't have a progressive aspect in German and because of that, we can't mark the action as perfect either if it isn't completed. Instead, we use Präsens and let the adverbial speak for itself:

Martin lebt seit zehn Jahren in England.

He is still living there.
If you wanted to say that Martin does not live in England any more, you would have to use a different adverbial, and mark the action as completed with a perfect tense:

Martin hat zehn Jahre lang in England gelebt. (chiefly)
Martin hat für zehn Jahre in England gelebt.

It's completed, he does not live there any more.

And there's also the other two combinations, albeit those are less common:

Martin hat seit zehn Jahren in England gelebt.

It's completed, but seit indicates that the action is ongoing, so the next sentence likely explains what happened during that time in the past. Again, because German has no progressive aspect in the verb tense, this logic is ruled by the adverbials alone.

Martin lebt zehn Jahre lang in England.
Martin lebt für zehn Jahre in England. (chiefly)

The adverbials zehn Jahre lang and für zehn Jahre are completed but the tense isn't a perfect tense so this means that he lives in England and that he will leave England as soon those ten years are completed.
(The form zehn Jahre lang is more common with perfect tenses and für zehn Jahre is more common with non-perfect tenses but that's just a rule of thumb. You can use both for both tenses.)
